# Does the sync command in ubuntu transfer all data in RAM to my HDD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My PC is frozen, running Ubuntu from a live CD, with important unsaved files open. If I use Magic SysRq to use the sync command, will that transfer all this unsaved data currently in RAM to HDD?

Update:

Ok, I've been informed dumping memory to disk isn't an option. I'm going to try the FireWire method now.

Answer (score 2):

No. From the man pages:

```
sync - flush file system buffers
```

Only outstanding write buffers are flushed. These are created when a program tries to write to a file on disk - instead of actually writing the file, the system writes it to free space in RAM, and then tells the program that the write is complete. This allows the program to continue with whatever the user wants it to do, and allows the system to wait until the disk is less busy to write the data actually to the drive.

This is why you should "safely remove" USB drives in Windows and not just pull them out (though these days, Windows just disables disk write caching on removable media)

Anything that is "unsaved" in an application, or anything that the application has not written to disk will not be affected at all by issuing a `sync` command.

Comment: I was getting ready to ask you to simplify it, but wow, that was a really good answer. Thanks. Can you tell me which command to use to completely dump memory to disk? Also, I'm running from Live CD, so will a memory dump still be put on my HDD? Is there any way to gain console and root access through Magic SysRq?

Comment: There is not exactly a command you can use for this (since the act of running such a command would change the state of the memory).  Moreover if you're running a LiveCD, the HDD will probably not even be mounted, making it effectively impossible to write to it. However, if your computer has FireWire ports and you have another PC running Linux, you can use [this method](http://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2010/04/reading-ram-using-firewire/) to dump the memory completely.

Comment: @Rayman The closest I can think would be hibernation ("suspend-to-disk") - But this requires you to be running of the harddrive and possibly swap space configured, neither of which a LiveCD will have. A LiveCD will not write to your HDD unless you manually mount it and manually write stuff to it with an application.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help guys. Dumping memory to disk isn't an option. Yeah, FireWire was the method I recently discovered, and that's what I'm going to try today.

Comment: You might need to do it a bit differently since IIRC raw1394 is no longer provided by default, but it should still be possible.